# Creating a struct with struct members in a source file

Tags: c++, struct, libraries

I am new to making custom libraries and am attempting to create a library that contains a struct data type that has some struct members. I want the children to be only used internally, but the parent struct with all of its components to be public for the user. the code I have written looks something like this:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H
private:
struct child1{
  int thing1;
  int thing2;
};
struct child2{
  char letter;
  int thing3;
};
public:
struct parent{
  int val;
  struct child1 name1;
  struct child2 name2;
};
#endif
```

so my question is, what should my .cpp header source file look like to create this, and is my .h header even correct? Tahks in advance

Comment: To me it looks ok, so you should try [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Access specifiers on apply to class members.  `private` and `public` are not valid outside that context.

Comment: Different set of rules apply to public vs private class members and public versus private types. You can have a public class member that's a private inner class/struct, or vice versa.

Comment: how would one then declare their struct in the source .cpp file?

Comment: when you refer to "child" in yout question, are you thinking in object inheritance? Or isn't that?

Comment: child, in this case, refers to a struct that I want to be exclusively used in the parent struct

Comment: Sorry, but "what should my .cpp header source file look like to create this" is off topic.

Comment: my question is primarily focused on the declaration of my parent struct in the .cpp source file. I am clueless as to if I need a .cpp or how I would go about making it for this specific case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, let's go...

Let's first differentiate declaration from definition. When you say `int x;`, you are telling to your computer that a variable called `x` exists, and it is an integer. On the other hand, when you say `x = 5;` you are defining `x` as number `5`.

The same can happen with functions, methods, classes and structs. As follows:

Function declaration:

```
int foo(int, char);
```

Function definition:

```
int foo (int a, char c) { ... do something ... }
```

And finally structs:

Struct declaration:

```
struct parent;
```

Struct definition:

```
struct parent {
    int thing1, thing2;
    struct child1 c;
};
```

Well, now remember that is the `.h` that you main program will include, then put in the `.h` just what the main will use

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
struct child1;
struct child2;
struct parent {
    struct child1 c1;
    struct child2 c2;
};
void process_something_internal(struct parent);
#endif
```

And in the your `.cpp` you can:

```
#include "header.h"
#ifdef HEADER_H
struct child1 {
    int t1, t2;
};
struct child2 {
    int t1, t2;
};
void process_something_internal(struct parent p) {
    int = p.child1.t1; // here you can access
    ...
}
#endif
```

Comment: what does the line `void process_something_internal(struct parent)` do? what is it's significance?

Comment: Your header file can't be used, see https://godbolt.org/z/aR0MPX

Answer (score 0):

Declaring your child structs into the CPP and storing them by value into your parent struct is impossible. To give the parent struct a correct binary representation, it is needed to know how much bytes the members take. This is only possible if the child structs are visible.

As this is C++, I'm gonna adopt the syntax to what we are used to, so instead of `struct parent p` I'm just be using `parent p`.

You have 2 options: The first one making the internals of the inner structs private:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <memory>
struct child1;
struct child2;
struct parent {
    std::unique_ptr<child1> c1;
    std::unique_ptr<child2> c2;
    ~parent();
};
#endif
```

Code at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/-JyMCL)

As you can see, we forward declared the 2 child structs and put some `unique_ptr` into the parent struct. This ensures encapsulation. I did also add a destructor for the parent struct, as your compiler should be able to call the destructor of the child structs when destroying the parent struct.

Alternative 2 is more easy in usage:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

struct parent {
 private:
  struct child1 {
    int thing1;
    int thing2;
  };
  struct child2 {
    char letter;
    int thing3;
  };

 public:
  int val;
  child1 name1;
  child2 name2;
};

#endif
```

Code at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/a2axpX)

In this technique, everything is defined in the same header file. It's simply marked as private, so it can't be accessed unless it was by a function of the parent struct. No memory allocations needed, as we now know the exact size of the child structs.

From my experience, I would recommend making all struct/class members of parent private. For the children, it shouldn't be accessed outside of this struct/class anyway. This will make your code easier to maintain.